# Hibernate Insert Greek Characters into Oracle

Tags: oracle, hibernate, special-characters

I have a requirement of inserting greek characters, such as 'ϕ', into Oracle. My existing DB structure wasn't supporting it. On investigating found various solutions and I adopted the solution of using NCLOB instead of CLOB. It works perfectly fine when I use unicode, 03A6, for 'ϕ', and use UNISTR function in SQL editor to insert. Like the one below.

**UPDATE config set CLOB = UNISTR('\03A6')**

However, it fails when I try to insert the character through my application, using hibernate. On debugging, I find that the string before inserting is '\u03A6'. After insert, I see it as ¿.

Can some one please help me how I can resolve this? How do I make use of UNISTR?

PN: I don't use any native sqls or hqls. I use entity object of the table.

**Edit:**

Hibernate version used is 3.5.6. Cannot change the version as there are so many other plugins dependent on this. Thus, cannot use **@Nationalized** or **@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.NClobType")** on my field in Hibernate Entity

Comment: It is possible that the character is stored correctly in the database but it doesn't show correctly on your screen (because your session, not the database, uses a character set that doesn't support Greek letters). To find out what's stored, you can use the DUMP function. For example, `select UNISTR('\03A6'), dump(UNISTR('\03A6')) from dual` shows me the letter ϕ (because my front-end's character set supports it) and `Typ=1 Len=2: 3,166` - the description of a two-byte Unicode character. Use the DUMP function to see if the character is stored correctly in the database.

Comment: Not really. I can see ¿stored in the DB.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The database doesn't store weird symbols, it only stored bytes (zeros and ones). They are interpreted as whatever symbols by your front-end, whatever you use. You can't ever see a literal ¿ stored in the DB. Did you try what I suggested? It should take a few seconds.

Comment: Yep. I tried UNISTR query and I get the same result as yours i.e. Φ and Typ=1 Len=2: 3,166. And yes, I can see ¿ in the table both in SQL Developer and IntelliJ editors.

Comment: OK - you see ¿ "in the table" is the correct way to say it. That's what SQL Developer shows you. "In the database" you have the correct character (you checked that with DUMP). Next question: what's the operating system on the machine where you run SQL Developer?

Comment: It is windows. I have Oracle hosted in windows as well.

Comment: I have an answer, but don't have enough credits to post it. Before inserting into the DB, I identify unicode characters in the string and format it to append `&#x` in the beginning and `;` at the end. This encoded string will be displayed with its actual unicode in the UI. `Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
        for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
            if (CharUtils.isAscii(c)) {
                formatter.format("%c", c);
            } else {
                formatter.format("&#x%04x;", (int) c);
            }
        }

        formatter.toString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After racking my brain on different articles and trying so many options, I finally decided to tweak my code a bit to handle this in Java and not through hibernate or Oracle DB.

Before inserting into the DB, I identify unicode characters in the string and format it to append `&#x` in the beginning and `;` at the end. This encoded string will be displayed with its actual unicode in the UI (JSP, HTML) that is UTF-8 compliant. Below is the code.

```
Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
    for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
        if (CharUtils.isAscii(c)) {
            formatter.format("%c", c);
        } else {
            formatter.format("&#x%04x;", (int) c);
        }
    }

    String result = formatter.toString();
```

Ex:

```
String test = "ABC \uf06c DEF \uf06cGHI";
```

will be formatted to

`test = "ABC &#xf06c; DEF &#xf06c;GHI";`

This string when rendered in UI (and even in word doc) it displays it as

`ABC  DEF GHI`

I tried it with various unicode characters and it works fine.